# HTML: set table height as percentage

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a scrollable table that is 80% of the screen's height. The problem is that it does not work to just put `height: 80%` at the table class. If I would put a static value instead, e.g. `height: 500px` it works. Could someone please explain why the table behaves this way and how can I fix it? I am new to HTML and don't have much experience with it.

base.html:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
{% load static %}
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/base.css' %}">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container main fullheight">
    <div class="row" >

                <div class="col-xs-7 table-striped table table-fixed">
                    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
</script>
</body>
```

css:

```
div.col-xs-7 row{
    min-width: 100% !important;
    width:800px;
    max-height: 100% !important;
    height: 444px;

}






body {
    background: #8fb0a9;
}

.table{
 width:100%;
}
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed thead>th {
    background: #4d7275;
    color: #fff;
}

.table-fixed tbody tr td {
    background: #fff;
}

.table-fixed>thead>tr>th {
    border: 0 !important;
}

.table-fixed>tbody>tr>td:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}

.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead>tr>th {
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-left: 20px !important;
}

.table-fixed tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: 80% of what? If you want it definitely to be 80% of the viewport height then use 80vh

Answer (score 0):

The body element isn't 100% of the screen height so you need to set it otherwise it shrinks to the size of the content. See [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-page-width-height/) for an explanation. If you want to have a scrollable table then put that in a container div, set that container to either 80% and set the body element to 100% height or alternatively set the container to 80vh (useful explainer [here](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/))

Here's an example below:

```css
    body {
      background: #8fb0a9;
      height:100vh;
    }

    table {
      border-collapse:collapse;
    }

    td {
      border: 1px solid gray;
      padding: 0.75rem;
      font-size:1.5rem;
    }

    .table-container {
      height:80%;
      overflow-y:auto;
      scrollbar-gutter:stable;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row3</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row4</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row5</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row6</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row7</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row8</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row9</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row10</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```